# How to search wikipedia with search string and fetch data, parse and disply in my app...?

Tags: android, parsing, wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia

all
I have searched this in google, but I confused with lot of sites which are no clear step by step procedure I found.

If any have Idea what are all the things need to be done. Please guide me...!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks similar the demo app in "Beginning Android" book. There they will create the http request and will send data to the server. They will get a HTML response, in which they will parse the data and displays to the user.

The main problem is, if u hard code the tag names, in future if it gets changes, then your app may not work. So better check whether there is any library (jar file) available for the wikipedia app. and try to make use of that.

Regards,
SSuman185